# How to get max of same data excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro that put the max number of same transactions in column J.

For exapmle:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: This is what I tried, I don't know how to add the max function, could you help me please!

Comment: For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 
    Set cel = Range("F:F").Find(what:=Cells(i, 6), lookat:=xlWhole) 
  If Not cel Is Nothing Then
       Cells(i, 22).Value = Cells(i, 18).Value
    End If
Next

Comment: Wouldn't the formula `=MAX(IF($F$2:$F$10=F2,$H$2:$H$10,0))` for J2 (and then copy down) do the same without VBA?  (array formula must be confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter)

Comment: Why do you need a macro?  Easily done with worksheet functions

Comment: personally, I'd use an array formula, like Dirk has suggested.  Much easier.

Comment: Yeah I can do it with an excel function, but I have more than 1000 rows, so I need to  automate this function by creating a macro vba

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using formula will be a better approach but if you particularly want VBA solution you could try something like this.

```
Sub Max_demo()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim c As Range
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row 'gives last row with data in column F

    For Each c In Range("J2:J" & lastRow)
        c.Value = Evaluate("=MAX(INDEX(($F$2:$F$" & lastRow & "=F" & c.Row & ")*($H$2:$H$" & lastRow & "),0))")
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code but, it copy the number and paste it in column J. The code don't look at the same transactions and find the max number

Comment: Do not encourage this kind of "code for me" answers @Mrig

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using a custom function like this one:

```
Function MaxIf(ByVal rngCol As Range, ByVal rngCol2 As Range, ByVal rngCompare As Range) As Long
MaxIf = 0
For Each c In Intersect(rngCol.Cells, rngCol.Parent.UsedRange).Cells
    If c.Value = rngCompare.Value Then
        If Cells(c.Row, rngCol2.Column).Value > MaxIf Then MaxIf = Cells(c.Row, rngCol2.Column).Value
    End If
Next c
```

Use `=MaxIf(first column, second column, cell)` and it should give you the value you've been looking for.

Comment: Could you please explain you code , I tried it but it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

Here are three worksheet formulas that will do what you want.

The first and third formulas are entered normally.

Note that the second formula is surrounded by braces `{...}`.  This is an array formula and you do not type the braces yourself.  Rather you enter the formula and then confirm it by holding down <kbd>ctrl + shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

### Formulas

[image]

### Results

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have more than 1000 rows, so I need to automate this function by creating a macro vba .Could you please transforme that into a vba macro

Comment: You could easily copy it down the 1000 rows (select the range, and Fill Down).   And if your data is a `Table`, it will fill automatically when you enter the formula in the first row.

Comment: The other problem is that my macro have other functions using this value, so the other fucntions will not work in this case (because I executed the macro with out inputs for other functions)